# Removing the bullets of the subsections in toc?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am working with the `beamer`, to create some slides.
How can I remove the bullets of the subsections in the table of contents ?

Comment: could you provide a MWE for folks to play with?

Comment: It would be super awesome if you could create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that community members could copy-and-paste to work with, rather than creating something from scratch.

Comment: sure,, I put this in the preamble :

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Contents}
  \tiny{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
  \end{frame}
}


and simply use the toc command in a frame : 

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents[pausesection]}

Comment: @shahb we need to know which theme(s) you are using. Please add to your question a complete simple document with the relevant settings (again, important things to include: the used theme(S)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine the `subsection in toc` template; after a new request made in a comment, one can use

```
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded]
```

for the inner ToCs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=2em\inserttocsubsection\par}

\AtBeginSection[]{% 
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Contents} 
\tiny\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded] 
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{General Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section A}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Test Section B}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The general ToC:

[image]

The inner ToC for the first section:

[image]

The inner ToC for the second section:

[image]

By the way, `\tiny` doesn't receive arguments.

Comment: Gonzalo Medina , thanks a lot.. it works for me ;-) 
however the table of content before each section is shadowed. I used this in preamble : 

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Contents}
  \tiny{\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]}
  \end{frame}
}

I'd like to highlight the section and subsection parts together .. any idea ?

Comment: @shahb please, I insist, which theme(s) are you using?

Comment: i am using warsaw. This is exactly my preamble :

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\newcommand{\schwa}{\raisebox{1ex}{\begin{turn}{180}e\end{turn}}}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=2em\inserttocsubsection\par}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Contents}
  \tiny{\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]}
  \end{frame}
}

Comment: @shahb Ah, OK. I've updated my answer; please let me know if that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Gonzalo Medina .. that really helped me ! thanks

Comment: I am new to this place, did you mean flag the answer that worked ?

Comment: @shahb you can perform two actions: up-voting good answers, by clicking the "up-arrow" shape to the left of the answer(s), and accepting an answer (there's a check-mark also to the right). Here you can find some info on [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954). The idea is to up-vote good answers and to accept the one you consider best solved your problem. In each of your questions you can up-vote more than one answer, but you can only accept one.